# Place Return Value in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, return

I have a .js file which contains a function that returns HTML.  How can I call this function from my .html and have its return placed where the call was made?

**my.html**

```
<body>
    //should make the HTML tag for a <h1>h1</h1> or <h2>h2</h2>
    <script>
        my.js->myFunction();  //what goes here?
    </script>
</body>
```

**my.js**

```
function myFunction(){
    if(true){
        return "<h1>h1</h1>";
    }
    else{
        return "<h2>h2</h2>";
    }
}
```

I am using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using any framework (jQuery, AngularJS, etc.), you can du this

```
<p id="p1"></p>

<script>

function myFunction(){
    var text = "";
    if(true){
         text = "True";
    }
    else{
         text = "False";
    }
    $("#p1").html(text);
}

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, but how can I do this with my return value dynamically?  Also, I am using jQuery.  I forgot to mention.

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  But that is still hardcoded text.  How can I do it with the example as seen in my question?

Comment: Updated again... Try to think about what is actually happen and you could figure the logic out (and perhaps get downvoted less :p)

Comment: Again, thanks.  Not quite what I am looking for, but it definitely gives me a place to play around.  I am going to work with this, then I will be back with my big green checkmark if I can figure it out to work with my example above :-) (where I do not know the id=p1)

Comment: With jQuery you can define the selected element with the help of various selectors:
https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/
I think you are approaching the problem from a non jQuery perspective if you don't know the element you want to place the text in.

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking from a PHP way of thinking. Javascript makes changes directly to the DOM (Document Object Model) and does not need to be inserted inline with HTML. Take this for example:

```
<p> Hello <php echo "World"; ?> </p>
```

That is the PHP way to do it. In Contrast, here is the Javascript way to do it:

```
<p> Hello <span id="output"></span> </p>

<script>
   document.getElementById("output").innerHTML="World";
</script>
```

notice the use of `document` here. That is the "D" in DOM. We are looking for an element nested in `document` with an id of "output" and changing its HTML to "World".

Comment: Thank you, but how can I do this with my return value dynamically?